# use spark-shell to group data and find mean on distinct dates from json files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a directory with 10 days of separate data Folders. Each Date folder has a JSON files as following.

```
[{"value": 5,"count" : 16,"currency":"EUR","date" : "2021-01-10"},{"value": 7,"count" : 166,"currency":"USD","date" : "2021-01-10"},{"value": 2,"count" : 188,"currency":"USD","date" : "2021-01-10"},{"value": 3,"count" : 114,"currency":"GBP","date" : "2021-01-11"},{"value": 5,"count" : 80,"currency":"USD","date" : "2021-01-11"},{"value": 10,"count" : 41,"currency":"GBP","date" : "2021-01-12"},{"value": 7,"count" : 84,"currency":"USD","date" : "2021-01-12"},{"value": 3,"count" : 147,"currency":"EUR","date" : "2021-01-15"},{"value": 2,"count" : 172,"currency":"USD","date" : "2021-01-15"},{"value": 10,"count" : 118,"currency":"USD","date" : "2021-01-15"}]
```

I have read the data using

```
val sc = sqlContext
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read.json("/Users/khan/directory/*/*.json")
```

I want to read the last 3 available days and group data by date and currency and find mean value where currency is in USD

**My Idea:**

```
dates_currency = df.select('date', 'currency').distinct().groupBy(desc('date', 'currency')).limit(3)
dates_currency.select('date', 'currency').distinct().where('currency'=='USD').mean()
```

I am having problem with syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dense_rank` to get the 3 most recent days:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val usd_mean = df.withColumn("rank", dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy("currency").orderBy(desc("date"))))
                 .filter("rank <= 3 and currency = 'USD'")
                 .groupBy("date")
                 .agg(mean("value"))

usd_mean.show()
+----------+----------+
|      date|avg(value)|
+----------+----------+
|2021-01-15|       6.0|
|2021-01-12|       7.0|
|2021-01-11|       5.0|
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: I want to get mean for separate dates, and No Partition is Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.